# set default audio track for mkv movies

Tags: linux, bash, audio, video, matroska

i am currently running a bash script on my linux debian system to copy some dvds. I am using makemkv for that. I also use minidlna to share the movies with my other devices in my network. The Problem i have is that i can not watch the movies in german. My PS4 for example can choose 2 or 3 languages but not all of them and most of the time german is not even an option. My VLC Player has no problems. So i thought setting the default audio track would do it. I found the programm called mkvtoolnix but i do not know how to use it for this. I only find answers for the GUI Version but im using a headless Server. So what precise command i need to use?

I tried something like this:

```
mkvmerge --default-language de 'movie.mkv'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can change default track number using `mkvpropedit` command from the same tool chain as `mkvmerge`:

```
mkvpropedit movie.mkv --edit track:a1 --set flag-default=0 --edit track:a2 --set flag-default=1
```

Just set the default track number to the one you would like to have (e.g. the one in German).

More info: https://mkvtoolnix.download/doc/mkvpropedit.html